# Exempting Delete Button in character limit

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I recently created a transliterate app that translates a word to Baybayin (Philippine Natiobak Writing System). I created a bunch of buttons that can scroll down to represent its keyboard. one of them is a Delete button to delete a word typed. I added a feature of limiting characters in the text field. I know that there is a feature for this in Flutter Text Field but as my app doesn't have a keyboard, and only relies on the buttons I created, it did not work so I need to create my own way of limiting characters. And I did that on my buttons. But the problem is, so is my delete button. I wanted to exempt the Delete button on the limitation and can be accessed even though the character reaches its limit. I tried multiple ways to do this but I can't figure out how.

here is the code that surrounds this problem. This is not the full code because the full code will surpass the limited characters of Stack Overflow.

```
   if(btntxt == "Delete"){
      translate.text = '';
      res = translateOutput.text = '';
      d = 0;
      isAbsorb = false;
    }


    else if(btntxt == "B"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'b';
      res = output +'b+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ba"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ba';
      res = output +'b';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Be"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'be';
      res = output +'be';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Bi"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'bi';
      res = output +'bi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Bo'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'bo';
      res = output +"bo";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Bu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'bu';
      res = output + 'bu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "K"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'k';
      res = output +'k+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ka"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ka';
      res = output +'k';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ke"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ke';
      res = output +'ke';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ki"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ki';
      res = output +'ki';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Ko'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ko';
      res = output +"ko";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ku"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ku';
      res = output + 'ku';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "D"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'd';
      res = output +'d+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Da"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'da';
      res = output +'d';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "De"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'de';
      res = output +'de';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Di"){

      translate.text= texttodisplay + 'di';
      res = output +'di';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Do'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'do';
      res = output +"do";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Du"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'du';
      res = output + 'du';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "G"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ga';
      res = output +'g+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ga"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ga';
      res = output +'g';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ge"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ge';
      res = output +'ge';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Gi"){

      translate.text= texttodisplay + 'gi';
      res = output +'gi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Go'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'go';
      res = output +"go";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Gu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'gu';
      res = output + 'gu';
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "H"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'h';
      res = output +'h+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ha"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ha';
      res = output +'h';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "He"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'he';
      res = output +'he';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Hi"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'hi';
      res = output +'hi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Ho'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ho';
      res = output +"ho";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Hu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'hu';
      res = output + 'hu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "L"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'l';
      res = output +'l+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "La"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'la';
      res = output +'l';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Le"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'le';
      res = output +'le';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Li"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'li';
      res = output +'li';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Lo'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'lo';
      res = output +"lo";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Lu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'lu';
      res = output + 'lu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == 'M'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'm';
      res = output +'m+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ma"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ma';
      res = output +'m';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Me"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'me';
      res = output +'me';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Mi"){

      translate.text= texttodisplay + 'mi';
      res = output +'mi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Mo'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'mo';
      res = output +"mo";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Mu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'mu';
      res = output + 'mu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "N"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'n';
      res = output +'n+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Na"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'na';
      res = output +'n';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ne"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ne';
      res = output +'ne';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ni"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ni';
      res = output +'ni';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'No'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'no';
      res = output +"no";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Nu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'nu';
      res = output + 'nu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }
    else if(btntxt == "Ng"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ng';
      res = output +'N+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Nga"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'nga';
      res = output +'N';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Nge"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'nge';
      res = output +'Ne';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ngi"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ngi';
      res = output +'Ni';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Ngo'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ngo';
      res = output +"No";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Nu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ngu';
      res = output + 'Nu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "P"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'pa';
      res = output +'p+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Pa"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'pa';
      res = output +'p';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Be"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'pe';
      res = output +'pe';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Pi"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'pi';
      res = output +'Pi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Po'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'po';
      res = output +"po";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Pu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'pu';
      res = output + 'pu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }
    else if(btntxt == "R"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'r';
      res = output +'d+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ra"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ra';
      res = output +'d';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Re"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 're';
      res = output +'de';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ri"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ri';
      res = output +'di';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Do'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ro';
      res = output +"do";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ru"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'Ru';
      res = output + 'du';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "S"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 's';
      res = output +'s+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Sa"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'sa';
      res = output +'s';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Se"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'se';
      res = output +'se';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Si"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'si';
      res = output +'si';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'So'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'so';
      res = output +"so";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Su"){
      text = texttodisplay + 'su';
      res = output + 'su';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "T"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 't';
      res = output +'t+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ta"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ta';
      res = output +'t';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Te"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'te';
      res = output +'te';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ti"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ti';
      res = output +'ti';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'To'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'to';
      res = output +"to";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Tu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'tu';
      res = output + 'tu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "W"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'w';
      res = output +'w+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Wa"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'wa';
      res = output +'w';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "We"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'we';
      res = output +'we';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Wi"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'wi';
      res = output +'wi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Wo'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'wo';
      res = output +"wo";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "wu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'wu';
      res = output + 'wu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "Y"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'y';
      res = output +'y+';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ya"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ya';
      res = output +'y';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Ye"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ye';
      res = output +'ye';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Yi"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'yi';
      res = output +'yi';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'Yo'){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'yo';
      res = output +"yo";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "Yu"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'yu';
      res = output + 'yu';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "A"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'a';
      res = output +'A';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "E"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'e';
      res = output +'E';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "I"){

      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'i';
      res = output +'I';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "O"){

      translate.text= texttodisplay + 'o';
      res = output +'O';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == 'U'){
      translate.text= texttodisplay + 'u';
      res = output +"U";
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    } else if (btntxt == "."){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + '.';
      res = output + '.';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == ","){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + ',';
      res = output +',';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }
    else if(btntxt == "Mga"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'mga';
      res = output +'mN';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }

    else if(btntxt == "ng"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'ng';
      res = output +'nN';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }
    else if(btntxt == "Nang"){
      translate.text = texttodisplay + 'nang';
      res = output +'nN';
      d++;
      isAbsorb = true;
    }
    else{
      translate.text = texttodisplay+btntxt;
      res = texttodisplay+btntxt;
    }

    setState(() {
      texttodisplay = translate.text;
      output = res;

    });
  }
  bool AbsorbPointers(){
  

    if(d == 20 && isAbsorb == true){
      return true;

    }
    else if(d != 20 || isAbsorb == false){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }

  }
  Widget customKeyboard(String btnval){

   setState(() {
     if(y < 20){
       y++;


     }
   });
    return Expanded(
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          absorbing: AbsorbPointers(),

          child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                btnclicked(btnval);
               
                print(d);

              },
              child: Text('$btnval')
          ),
        )
```

Comment: What does "buttons that can scroll down to represent its keyboard" mean? Could you also clarify the character limit on the delete button? What's the expected and current behavior?

Comment: Also, isn't it more efficient to use [String.toLowerCase()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/toLowerCase.html) if you're just converting String to lowercase?

Comment: My buttons are in ListView so it can be scrollable on which buttons the user wants to press